# Using group by to get most recent record from table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that shows order numbers, order descriptions along with the date that they were placed.

Sometimes order numbers are repeated. I want to get all unique order numbers with descriptions but only show the most recent in the event of duplicates

```
orderID     orderInfo       dateAdded
1           cheese          2014-10-01
1           cheese+         2014-10-02
1           cheese&tomato   2014-10-03
2           bacon           2014-10-05
2           bacon           2014-10-04
2           bacon           2014-10-02
3           tuna            2014-09-30
```

So my query should return:

```
orderID     orderInfo       dateAdded
1           cheese&tomato   2014-10-03
2           bacon           2014-10-05
3           tuna            2014-09-30
```

I have tried:

```
select orderID, orderInfo from orders group by orderID
```

But this just gives me the first of each orderID, how do I get it to select the most recent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simple `LEFT JOIN` the table with itself `on orderID` **AND** add a join condition, `t1.dateAdded < t2.dateAdded`.

Finally you pick the results, where `t2.dateAdded` is null, and you have the latest entry per order.
(Because then, the result you have currently in `t1` is the latest date inside the join group)

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  test t1
LEFT JOIN
  test t2
ON
  t1.id = t2.id AND
  t1.dateAdded < t2.dateAdded
WHERE
  ISNULL (t2.dateAdded);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0629b2/1

But be aware that for *huge* tables this might be a *huge* join!

Look behind the scenes:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0629b2/3

As you can see, you need the rows where *t2_dateAdded* is null. But as you also can see: the result is already larger compared to the table. So in this example you created 6 additional join results - just to throw them away afterwards. (It is no problem for tables upto 100.000 entries I assume. Still running it on a server with 500.000 rows, and query executes in ~ 2 seconds.)

Comment: Yes, I think this works ... just testing it now. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using MAX() function

```
SELECT orderID,orderInfo,MAX(dateAdded) from (
  SELECT orderID,orderInfo,dateAdded from orders   ORDER BY dateAdded DESC) as t
   group by orderID
```

Comment: That gives me the date of the most recent order ... but it doesn't show the correct orderInfo against the order. It seems to show the date of the most recent order combined with the orderInfo of the first

Comment: I updated my post. I think this time will fetch correct results

Answer (score -1):

As you said, you want the most recent, so you could use:

```
select * from orders group by orderID order by dateAdded desc
```

Comment: This won't work. This gives the dates of the first orders and then sorts by these. It doesn't give me the date of the most recent

Comment: Did you even try to use it? Because in your question you just said you want the most recent, and to define recent it should be shown by date, not for the order.

Comment: I said the same, test it and indeed, does not work. You can delete this anwser.

Comment: @TioDavid Refresh it a few times and the result will differ. for me, it shows "cheese" for order id 1 - which is wrong. MySQL will Group FIRST - and then, since you did not provide a valid aggregation pick undefined results from the remaining fields within each group. *Usually* in the order of insertion - but after all *undefined*!

Comment: I added cheese, 2015-10-01 and this result does not appears however, it's the most recent, so it does not work.